# XCode Background Modes Crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background-mode

when i tried to enabled some background modes xcode crashes, long time ago i could enable the Audio, airplay etc. but i need background location update and i cant figure it out now.

Every time xcode crashes and re-open.I came across with developer blogs of Apple with similar issue but my entitlenments file is true without any problem. What is the solution?

I tried to add from info.plist but same result...[image: XCODE SCRREENSHOT]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding the below option in the info.plist file.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```